# Что делают эти строки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помоготе разобраться что делают эти 7 строк что я закоментировал.Не могу розобраться в длинных jQuery цепочках(
Код слайдера:

```
    var slideWidth=1663;
var sliderTimer;
$(function(){
$('.slidewrapper').width($('.slidewrapper').children().size()*slideWidth); //1
    sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,5000);
    $('.viewport').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(sliderTimer);
    },function(){
        sliderTimer=setInterval(nextSlide,5000);
    });
});

function nextSlide(){
    var currentSlide=parseInt($('.slidewrapper').data('current')); //2
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide>=$('.slidewrapper').children().size()) //3
    {
        $('.slidewrapper').css('left',-(currentSlide-2)*slideWidth);   //4
        $('.slidewrapper').append($('.slidewrapper').children().first().clone());  //5
        $('.slidewrapper').children().first().remove(); //6
        currentSlide--;                        
    }
        $('.slidewrapper').animate({left: -currentSlide*slideWidth},1000).data('current',currentSlide); //7
}
```

Comment: потому что код надо писать чем проще тем лучше, используя пробелы при этом, и ставя переносы строк между логическими блоками. в целом тут ваши _цепочки_ из трех вызовов вполне читаются как обычный текст.  Что может быть сложного в понимании `$(..).children().size()`? разве не ясно.что это кол-во дочерних элементов?  или `children().first().remove()` ?

Comment: Интересно, а jQuery кеширует запросы вроде `$('.slidewrapper')` или каждый раз в DOM ходит?

Comment: @vp_arth, каждый раз ходит

Comment: @Grundy, мог бы и кешировать, хотя бы до конца синхронного фрейма (Инвалидировать по setTimeout(0), например)

Comment: @vp_arth, но зачем? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для элемента `.slidewrapper` устанавливается ширина, равная произведению ширины одного слайда (дочернего элемента, children) на их количество
2. currentSlide присваивается значение атрибута `data-current` элемента `. slidewrapper`, приведенное к типу `integer`
3. Если `currentSlide` больше или равен числу слайдов
4. Для элемента `.slidewrapper` устанавливается css-свойство `left`, вычисляется смещение на два слайда влево (отрицательное значение)
5. В конец элемента `.slidewrapper` добавляется клон первого слайда (первого дочернего элемента)
6. Первый дочерний элемент удаляется
7. Для элемента `.slidewrapper` устанавливается css-свойство `left`, вычисляется смещение на 1 слайда влево (отрицательное значение). Изменение значения свойства происходит плавно, за 1000 мс (анимация). Для этого же элемента устанавливается атрибут `data-current` в значение `currentSlide`

Comment: Вы удивительным образом синхронизировались с @SergeyGornostaev или просто зарерайтили его ответ?

Comment: @vp_arth за 2 минуты не зарерайтишь :)

Comment: Синхрон конечно)

Comment: На самом деле, я просто не заметил 7 пунктов в вопросе)

Answer (score 2):

1. Установка элементу с классом slidewrapper ширины равной количеству
   дочерних элементов умноженных на slideWidth.
2. Присвоение переменной currentSlide целого числа из атрибута
   data-current элемента с классом slidewrapper.
3. Проверка на то, что currentSlide больше или равен количеству
   дочерних элементов элемента с классом slidewrapper.
4. Установка css-значения left элемента с классом slidewrapper равным
   отрицательному произведению currentSlide - 2 и slideWidth.
5. Добавление в элемент с классом slidewrapper копии первого дочернего
   элемента.
6. Удаление из элемента с классом slidewrapper первого дочернего
   элемента.
7. Анимированое изменение значения css-свойства left элемента с классом
   slidewrapper на отрицательное произведение currentSlide и
   slideWidth, а потом установка значения атрибута data-current равным
   currentSlide.